# How do you make it so that your Discord thread name uses the response from a certain question on the Google form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use a response from a google form as a thread title for my discord form threads. Anyone have any ideas? I appreciate any form of help since Javascript isn't my main language.

```
// The Post url to send the embed to. This is where you should paste your webhook link.
var POST_URL = "https://canary.discord.com/api/webhooks/1038081692671410247/M5qropuZp-XKYs6XlfWeT4YIa5vTnGBEB8fSjsNl7uYKRXA86iOvf49cbA6xIaEXh8Qq";

// onSubmit function that should be triggered when a new form is submitted.
function onSubmit(e) {
    // Get the form object
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    // Get all of the form's responses
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    // Get the latest response submitted to the form
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    // Get an array containing all the responses to each question
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    // Current items array to use in embed
    var items = [];
    // Current number characters being used in the current embed
    var currentEmbedCharacterNum = 0
    // Tracks part number for multi-embed responses
    var partNumber = 1;
    // Leave this null. This is used to keep track of the thread_id in future.
    var thread_id = null;

    // For loop to iterate through responses
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        // Get the question text
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        // Get the answer text
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        // If the answer is over a certain number of characters, break it into multiple parts.
        try {
            var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            var parts = answer;
        }

        // If the answer text is blank, skip this iteration.
        if (answer == "") {
            continue;
        }

        if (question.length > 256) {
            question = question.substring(0, 220) + "...";
        }

        // For loop to iterate through the parts of an answer
        for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            // Add the number of characters in a part to the total character count of this embed
            currentEmbedCharacterNum += parts[j].length + question.length;
            // If the total character count with this part included pushes the total over 5000 (Discord Embeds have a character limit)
            if (currentEmbedCharacterNum >= 5000) {
                // Send the embed
                if (thread_id == null) {
                    thread_id = sendEmbed(items, thread_name);
                } else {
                    sendFollowupEmbed(items, thread_id, partNumber, thread_name);
                    partNumber += 1;
                }
                // Wait a second so Discord doesn't get overwhelmed with requests
                Utilities.sleep(50)
                // Reset the character count and items array
                currentEmbedCharacterNum = 0;
                items = [];
            }

            // If there are multiple parts to an answer, add a (cont.) to the names.
            if (j == 0) {
                items.push({
                    "name": question,
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            } else {
                items.push({
                    "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            }
        }
    }
    // Send an embed to the webhook.
    if (thread_id == null) {
        thread_id = sendEmbed(items);
    } else {
        sendFollowupEmbed(items, thread_id, partNumber);
        partNumber += 1;
    }
};

// Function to send an embed to the webhook url.
function sendEmbed(items) {
    // Package the embed options into a variable
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "thread_name": "A nice thread name here",
            "embeds": [{
                "title": "Some nice title here",
                "color": 33023, // This is optional, you can look for decimal colour codes at https://convertingcolors.com/
                "fields": items,
                "footer": {
                    "text": "Some footer here"
                }
            }]
        })
    };
```

i tried using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response but it wasnt very clear on how to use it

Comment: I've got a repo where I describe how you can implement this functionality. Maybe this will help https://github.com/Kelo/Google-Forms-to-Discord-Extended#new-forum-channel-thread-for-each-response